# Why shows the emulator not the whole layout in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio since some weeks. After my first experience I'm building my first APK und have a problem with the Relative layout.

After I'm putting the stuff (ImageBtn, TextView) into it and trying to run the app in the emulator, it shows only the left side.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9vhH.png)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/beer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:text="Beer"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:text="Level 0"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/frenchfries" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:text="French Frits"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Level 0"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView13" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icecream" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:text="Ice Cream"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
        android:text="Level 0"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pizza"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton9"
        android:text="Pizza"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Level 0"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView17" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="102dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView18"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope you can help me to fix that problem.

Greetings Phil Newman

Comment: Check some length values that you used. Since we can't see xml layout, there is less we can do to help.

Comment: I've add the xml layout code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will present two ways I would do this if it was me. So you can also choose from this to suit your need.

**METHOD ONE**

You can use a `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation as the parent layout.
Use another `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation to host a two  `RelativeLayout`s. Each `RelativeLayout` will also contain the three components(`ImageButton`, `TextView`s).

Looks at an xml text I have presented here:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/beer" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:text="Beer"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:text="Level 0"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/frenchfries" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:text="French Frits"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:text="Level 0"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView1" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icecream" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:text="Ice Cream"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView102"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:text="Level 0"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView0"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView0" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pizza" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:text="Pizza"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:text="Level 0"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can analyse it carefully and just copy and paste depending on the number of buttons(your categories) you want.

**METHOD TWO**

Arrange everything well in the Relative layout (linearly or preferably a `LinearLayout`) and put the `RelativeLayout` in a `ScrollView` layout as the parent layout.  This will enable the user to scroll down and up if the widgets are out of view.

Also here is an `xml` for that:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/beer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:text="Beer"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:text="Level 0"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/frenchfries" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:text="French Frits"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"  -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:text="Level 0"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView13"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icecream" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:text="Ice Cream"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
        android:text="Level 0"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pizza" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton9"
        android:text="Pizza"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Level 0"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView17" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks you for the anwser. The first method is fine for me.